# is there an Ubuntu that every program is installed?

Tags: system-installation

is there an Ubuntu that every program is installed or at least it has the package of every program ?

my point is that I want to install Ubuntu to people who have no internet and I want to install some programs that they will use so how to do this?

even after I go there I do have internet but its slow so I want to install all my essential programs without internet how to do this ?

for example these are my essential programs(its just an example):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jfi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psensor

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller

wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtual-box-5.0
sudo apt-get install dkms

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calendar-indicator

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peterlevi/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install variety

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tomahawk/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomahawk


deb http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam (copy past this ppa to source)
sudo apt-get install steam

sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo apt-get install tree

apt-get install libclamunrar6
apt-get install clamav
apt-get install clamav-daemon
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:landronimirc/clamtk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clamtk
```

Comment: There is no distro that has all this preinstalled, you should customize your own iso with the packages you want http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: REALLY can I costomize my own iso ?? WOW ill try

Comment: why downgrade my post I am new to Linux I want to go for free piracy and i installed Ubuntu and I'll learn eventually

Comment: I did not down vote you and there is no way to know who did, unfortunately, not everyone likes to comment why they downvote, but they have there reasons http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15102/reason-for-question-beeing-downvoted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: no its not Possible duplicate of How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?